# How to use keyboard keys as mouse buttons?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

On Asus EEE PC 1005PX, the mouse buttons are pretty stiff. So, I want to use the `windows` key and the `menu` key on the keyboard as `left` and `right` mouse buttons respectively. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes you can, Install [btnx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/btnx) [image: Install btnx]
- After installation it will be found under **Application>>System Tools**

[image]

Comment: btnx wasn't available to me but I found a way in Ubuntu12 with http://askubuntu.com/questions/372526/how-can-i-use-my-keyboard-as-a-mouse

Comment: why is this accepted if you didn't try it?

Comment: Seems like btnx is only available for 10.04?