# How can I use my keyboard as a mouse?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, cursor

I'm using my keyboard more and more these days for basic command line stuff, vim editing, alt-tab window switching and the like.

Q) How can I use my number pad keys to move the cursor around on the screen without using the mouse?

I looked to try and install `btnx` as mentioned by others but it doesn't seem to exist anymore as an available package

I also tried <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>numlock</kbd> as mentioned by another but that didn't work either (just turns numlock on/off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numlock</kbd> does actually work... but you have to enable "Pointer Keys" first

To enable "Pointer Keys":

You can find this under:

```
-> System Settings...
  -> Keyboard Layout...
    -> Options
      -> Miscellaneous compatibility options 
        -> Toggle PointerKeys with Shift + Numlock
```

as shown here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The checkbox was unchecked for me by default and so I checked it.

Now Shift+Numlock *does* turn the feature on!

btw '`5`' is the button click key